# T7-01 not there?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I'm doing the quest "Weapon of the Jedi" Part: Investigate the forge entrance, 
I investigate the whole thing, defeat Bengal Moor, and when I'm about to turn the quest in it says "you have to have T7-01 with you" or something. The problem is, he is not there because he did not follow me from the start of the quest. He is not yet my companion so I can't summon him. What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be working for people who obtained a "temporary" companion after Patch 4.0 (open the Companions and Contacts window to summon them), but is broken for people who had a temp companion before the patch; see [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/swtor/comments/3pkdaw/weapon_of_the_jedi_is_impossible_to_complete_for/cw738r9?context=1).

(For clarity, in pre-4.0 content most companions temporarily accompany you during critical quests before becoming "permanent" companions; it's this temporary state that was not properly migrated into the new system.)

At this point, all you can do is wait for it to be fixed — or, since you are on the starter planet, you might opt to delete the character and start over.

Comment: I would wait, chances are BW will be patching certain bugs pretty quickly in the first week before the official release.