# SWTOR companions after update 4.0

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I have to finish a quest on Tatooine with Andronikos revel as my companion, but I can not summon him.

This appears to be a similar issue to [a differant question that has been asked](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/240371/t7-01-not-there) except I already had Andronikos as a vompanion, and he has simply dissapeared from the available companions list.

This was not an issue before update 4.0. I have double checked that I can not access him from the companion list (<kbd>N</kbd>) or the crafting panel (<kbd>B</kbd>).

How can I summon my companion?

Comment: Ive made some edits to improve the quality of your question,and include the part making it differant to the suggested duplicate. Please make sure you address these issues with a comment or an edit. Misusing the answer post will have your comments removed, and eventually restrict you from answering other users posts.

Comment: On another note, this is a very similar issue to the suggested duplicate, even if it is not the same one. Given that the answer to the duplicate question is "there is a known bug concerning this feature, and their trying to fix it", this most likely also effects the compa ion system in the way that you describe, and I would suspect that if no better answer pops up, a patch should fix this.